# Does $x\cdot 0 = 0$ follow from the field axioms alone?

Tags: field-theory, axioms

From the [field axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) *alone*, does it follow that $x \cdot 0 = 0$ for all $x$?

All I would like is a statement that it can or cannot be done (hints not necessary). I would like to do it myself; I just don't want to waste my time if it's not true. Then I will post my own answer when I get it.

I have tried to prove it by taking some $y\neq 0$, and then using multiplication's distributivity over addition to argue that: $x\cdot 0 = x \cdot (y + -y) = x\cdot y + x\cdot -y$. However I cannot find a way to show that $x\cdot -y = -(x\cdot y)$ without using what I want to prove in the first place.

Comment: Yep, definitely possible! Can also be done with just ring axioms. By the way, you have the right pieces on the board, just start differently.

Comment: $x= x\cdot 1=x\cdot (1+0)=x+x\cdot0 \Rightarrow x\cdot0=0$

Comment: Do I say that $x\cdot 0 = x\cdot (0+0) = x\cdot 0 + x\cdot 0$, and then show that the only element that can satisfy this relationship is $0$?

Comment: Actually the Peano axiom number 6 says $x \dot{} 0= 0$

Comment: $x\cdot (-y)=-(x\cdot y)$ as $x\cdot (-y)+x\cdot y=x\cdot (-y+y)=x\cdot 0=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** In any ring we have $0=0+0$ and distributivity.

Answer (score 1):

This two equations can be taken from field axioms:
$$x.(0+ 0)= x. 0$$
$$x.(0+ 0)= x. 0 + x. 0$$
thus, we have
$$x. 0 = x. 0 + x. 0$$
and with this, we have proved that $x. 0 = 0$.